Is a custom __pc Person Account field literally the same field as the Contact field?
We have enabled Person Account in our organisation. I can see that when a custom Contact field is created, a corresponding __pc field is created on the Account object.
When I click on the __pc field in the Account, I am re-routed to the __c field on the Contact.

Is that because they are (from Salesforce's point of view) literally the same field?

If I populate information on custom_field__c, is the same info
present in custom_field__pc?

If I wrote code that populates the __pc
field, will the __c field also be populated by default?


And for standard Person Account fields - if I click e.g. PersonEmail, I'm not taken to Email on the Contact record, I stay on the Organisation record.

Are Email and PersonEmail still the 'same' field? Or are they different fields?
Are they linked in any way?


I believe Person Account is a smoke and mirrors combination of Account and Contact, which is why you see these interesting behaviours.

When you enable person account in a salesforce org, it combines Contact and Account. So if you create a record in PersonAccount, salesforce in backend will create a contact record, with blank record type for the same.
As both these objects "Account" and "Contact" are merged into one PersonAccount (Account) object. Hence you see this behaviour.
Even when you copy PersonContactId from Account field and try to open the contact, it would redirect you to account record.
If I populate information on custom_field__c, is the same info present in custom_field__pc? Yes
If I wrote code that populates the __pc field, will the __c field also be populated by default? Yes
If you populate something in PersonEmail, the same will auto reflect in Email field of the connected Contact, and vice-versa, if you update the Email field on Contact the same will update on Account's PersonEmail too.
